# If both drivers reach the sponsor's race goal, will you receive once or twice the cash bonus?

Tags: motorsport-manager

If both drivers reach the sponsor's race goal, will you receive once or twice the cash bonus?

In other words, does the cash bonus given by sponsors is for the team or for each driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have both drivers complete your sponsor's goal you only receive your bonus once. So you only need to make sure one driver passes your goal, although you of course want both drivers to do well.